Enable Sort by Date Modified for all Win 10 Picture Folders
Is it possible to modify the registry or something to make Sort by Date Modified available as a default option for sorting image folders across everything in Windows?
I can enable it one by one folder but for all my galleries it'd be nice to see what the latest I've captured is.
I've come across similar answers for apply to all subfolders, but this doesn't apply making a non-default sort option available to those subfolders. Answers like cascading simple properties to all folders such as this do not address what I am looking for.

You should already be able to do this by setting the view settings of the folder containing images files.

I understand I can do this individually, but I've got hundreds of folders across multiple drives with different levels of nesting depending on projects.

It sounds like you should use a different shell other than File Explorer or use a third-party application that enhances File Explorer. I personally would just get better an organization. File Explorer at the surface supports what you want to do it’s just limited in it’s scope

Does this answer your question? What are 'folders of this type' in Windows 10? . There are various folder types. Set the view for Pictures to include Date Modified. After that, any folder under the Pictures library, or a folder elsewhere that contains exclusively image files, should include that column.

It does not, I apologize for not linking to in my question but this is exactly the kind of answer I kept finding that did not help me. I want to change the default options for all picture folders to add the Date Modified column as an option. This is only something I can find in advanced settings per folder right now.
